# Drawing a WebGLRenderTarget to screen

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, shader, gpgpu

Drawing a WebGLRenderTarget to screen

I’m working on a GPGPU animation starting with Joshua Koo’s excellent [flocking example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_gpgpu_birds). In order to aid any future debugging I would like to render the textures to the screen but I'm getting strange results. Here’s the approach I’ve taken:

1. Create a new scene called debugScene.
2. Create an OrthographicCamera called cameraRTT.
3. Create 2 meshes (posDebugQuad and velDebugQuad) containing a PlaneBufferGeometry and a pass through shader (see below).
4. Add meshes to debugScene and position to the left of the screen.

Then, each frame I do the following:

1. Set the material.uniforms.texture.value of posDebugQuad and velDebugQuad to the existing position and velocity WebGLRenderTarget objects.
2. Render to my WebGLRenderer using debugScene and cameraRTT.

This maps the GPGPU textures to my mesh objects but results in the position data being reduced to 0,0,0 (or close to this). All I see is a fuzzy grey ball of 4000 birds rotating in the centre of the screen. Somewhere in this process I appear to be resetting the position data. Or maybe I am taking the wrong approach to this.

I have tried many different approaches including cloning the GPGPU WebGLRenderTarget objects and using MeshBasicMaterial and map. Weirdly, if I use a PerspectiveCamera instead or othographic the positioning problem seems to disappear. But then, even stranger, when I try to position the debug meshes in the centre of the screen, the problem comes back. Why would the x/y values of a mesh interfere with the drawing of its texture's pixels?

Here are the pass through shaders I’ve written. As far as I can see, they should not be altering the texture:

```
<!-- debug fragment shader -->
<script id="fragment_shader_debug" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    uniform vec2 resolution;
    uniform sampler2D texture;
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, vec2(gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy));
    }
</script>

<!-- debug vertex shader -->
<script id="vertex_shader_debug" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    void main() {
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    }
</script>
```

Here is the [rest of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/x2c6r54k/). Any help would be amazing. I've been stuck on this for a long time.

Comment: I'll try to come back to this question soon with greater attention but my quick advice would be to 100% check your units, because remember that even if you upload data using a Uint8Array for your buffers, sampling it in a texture within your shader will still give you values between 0 and 1.

Comment: `gl_FragCoord.xy` are in rendertarget pixel coordinates. If your render target is the canvas then they're going to be different depending on where you draw your quad.

Comment: Thanks guys. @BrendanAnnable, I'm using Float32Array buffers so you appear to have found the problem. I didn't realise that merely passing this type buffer to a shader as a sample can affect it like this. The numbers in the Flota32Array range from -400 - 400. I guess there is no way of drawing a WebGLRenderTarget that uses a this type of buffer to the screen? Perhaps the best way to fix this is to use a buffer containing 0-1 values (is there such a buffer? - I can't find this), set precision to high and then map these values to -400 - 400 in the vertex shader.

Comment: In my limited experience, I've had success just mapping input values back to their expected values as you said, i.e. back to [-400,400]. If they are integer values you might need to round using floor(value + 0.5) to remove any precision errors.